# How to initialize state in componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle for React16.x?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I used to initialize state in componentWillReceiveProps using this.state = ... 
By the way, it's deprecated in React16.x
It's recommended to use this.setState instead of this.state = .
But I have to initialize state in componentWillReceiveProps, because some old states remains if I use this.setState function.
Do you have any idea?
Please advise me.
Thanks

Comment: do you mean, you need to reinitialise/reset  it

Comment: I've attempted to answer based on your question, please let me know if i need to elaborate as I might have misunderstood what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are initializing state in one of the lifecycle methods - you only want to do this in the constructor.

Typically, you'd initialize state in the constructor, or with `setInitialState`

```
constructor() {
  this.state = { foo: 'bar' }
}

componentWillReceiveProps() {
  this.setState({ foo: 'baz' })
}
```

From there, you can call `setState` in your lifecycle methods.

For initializing state, you would use `this.state  = {}` in the constructor, and for updating state call `this.setState()`.

---

Also, you mentioned this...

> By the way, it's deprecated in React16.x It's recommended to use this.setState instead of this.state =

Can you point me to where you see this in the documentation? According to https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#breaking-changes there are some changes to the way setState behaves in the context of react lifecycle methods, but I haven't found anything to validate your claim

Comment: Ok, so I think I understood correctly. Instead of calling `this.state = { foo: 'bar' }` you should be using `this.setState({ foo: 'baz' })` for state related updates. Use `this.state` for your initial setup of state in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're defining any method in reactjs, do it this way:

```
increment: function(){
       this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
       })
     }
```

// I'm adding something to the previous state of count here.